# Sendgrid Event notification POST data is always null

Tags: codeigniter, webhooks, sendgrid

I have added a url to get the POST response from Sendgrid for event notification

code to capture result is like

```
$result = file_get_contents('php://input');
$events = json_decode($result, true);
$this->db->insert('delivery_temp', ['response' => $events]);
```

I am always getting the result as NULL when I try by hitting Test your integration button in sendgrid. 
The above code is added in index function of a controller in codeigniter.
url is like http://testing.site_name.com/email_status
Thanks in advance